# How can I open a new Finder window on every click on the Finder Icon?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

is there anywhere a script or a workaround, or even just a .plist file, where i can manage to open a new finder window by clicking on the finder icon in the dock?

When a Finder window is already open, a click on the Finder icon just shows me the opened window, but doesn't open a new one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The real question is why clicking the icon when no Finder windows are already open sometimes does nothing...

Comment: it's been ten years, but there's still no proper way to achieve this. it's especially annoying when you click finder on dock and it jumps to an open finder window in another desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour happens beacuse the dock just launches an app. Finder is classified as an app, so it will open/show the app window, you will need to open a new window within the app.

You can use the keyboard short cut CMD + N, and if you are not in the app press CMD + Tab to open it first.

You could possibly try using [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/), which makes custom keystrokes, so you could assign O to opening a new finder window

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [Hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/).

I do this for most of my software (Finder, Terminal, Chrome, etc...). Clicking on the application icon sends the application a `Command + N`.

It's non-free though.